# Hello Next.js [...nextAuth].js File Session Function Calling Questions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, session, next.js14

I'm just asking you to check this part because I'm working on a project related to Next.js and the session part doesn't seem to be working in the callback function during the login logic implementation

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import {connectDB} from "@/util/mongoDbDatabase";
import {MongoDBAdapter} from "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter";
import CustomCredentialsProvider from "@/app/CredentialsProvider";
export const options = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
                name: "credentials",
                async authorize(credentials) {
                    const client = await connectDB
                    const db = client.db("yoong")
                    const user = await db.collection("member").findOne({userId : credentials.userId,   password : credentials.password})
                    if(!user){
                        return null
                    }
                    return user;
                },
        }),
    ],
    session: {
        strategy: 'session',
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 //30일
    },
    callbacks: {
        async session(session, user) {
            const client = await connectDB
            const db = client.db("yoong")
            db.collection("session").insertOne(user)
            return session;
        },
    },
        adapter : await MongoDBAdapter(await connectDB),
        secret : process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};

const CustomLoginPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <CustomCredentialsProvider/>
        </div>
    );
};
export default NextAuth(options);
export const CustomLogin = CustomLoginPage;
```

Basic logic implemented a personal login page to implement a login method as a session method and applied session information to MongoDB

```
'use client'
import {useState} from "react";
import {signIn} from "next-auth/react";
import {useRouter} from "next/navigation";
export default function CustomCredentialsProvider({session}) {
    let [id, setId] = useState("")
    let [password, setPassword] = useState("")
    let router = useRouter()
    async function handleSignIn(){
        const result = await signIn('credentials', {
            redirect: false, // 로그인 성공 시 자동으로 페이지를 이동하지 않도록 설정
            userId: id,
            password: password,
            callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/main'
        });
        if(result.error !== undefined && result.error !== null && result.error !== ""){
            alert("로그인에 실패했습니다 사유 : " + result.error)
        }else{
            alert("로그인 성공 : " + result)
            console.log(result)
            await router.push("/main")
        }
    }
 
    return (
        <div className="main">
            < img src="/ProjectYoongMain.png" className="main-image"></img>
            <div className="login">
                <h1>Welcome To PJYoong</h1>
                <div className="input-login">
                    <p>ID</p>
                    <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>{setId(e.target.value)}} placeholder="아이디를 입력하세요" style={{right: 20 + "px"}}></input>
                </div>
                <div className="input-login">
                    <p>PW</p>
                    <input type="password" onChange={(e)=>{setPassword(e.target.value)}} placeholder="비밀번호를 입력하세요"></input>
                </div>
                <div className="f-right">
                    <button type="button" onClick={
                        handleSignIn
                    }>로그인</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The above code is a custom login code. I'm sharing the reference

First of all, when I logged in before the problem, the login worked normally

```
async function handleSignIn(){
        const result = await signIn('credentials', {
            redirect: false, // 로그인 성공 시 자동으로 페이지를 이동하지 않도록 설정
            userId: id,
            password: password,
            callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/main'
        });
        if(result.error !== undefined && result.error !== null && result.error !== ""){
            alert("로그인에 실패했습니다 사유 : " + result.error)
        }else{
            alert("로그인 성공 : " + result)
            console.log(result)
            await router.push("/main")
        }
    }
```

When I took a log from the code above, I checked the login information normally, and the server also checked the user login information by checking the DB using the login information. But whether the next step, the callback, doesn't work

```
  callbacks: {
        async session(session, user) {
            const client = await connectDB
            const db = client.db("yoong")
            db.collection("session").insertOne(user)
            return session;
        },
    },
```

Even if I log in from the code above, nothing comes out, and on the /main page that is accessed after login, it was confirmed that the session information was null when outputting the session information with the getServerSession() function. (I definitely logged in and received the login information.) The session information was not stored in the DB that stores the session. I would like to ask if there is anything I missed in that part
Additionally, I checked to see if session information was stored on other storage or cookies (not implemented as a feature, but did not check session information when login was complete), but there was no session information in local storage, session storage, and cookies either